# Can I create a asp.net web application with embedded database

Tags: asp.net

I want to develop a asp.net web application, more like a invoice system. I was thinking how to start developing it ?

I know how to create web forms etc, but I always used a sql server for data storage, but this time my boss asks to develop a web application so that we will hand it over to client with just a folder and they start using it.

please guide me in right direction

Answer (score -2):

Your boss needs to update himself. You can have a normal web app and use SQL Server storage, just build a deploy script that the clients must run, to deploy the system.

Also dont go for ASP.Net Web Forms, if you want to to something nice, testable and future proof you should MVC instead and maybe go the extra mile and have a REST interface.

In any case and since that's what you asked, for embeded databases check SQL Lite.

Comment: I downvoted for needlessly bringing up Web Forms vs MVC.